# Are 'Let's have/take something to eat/drink' grammatical and meaningful?

Tags: vocabulary

I have seen them in a book written by non-natives.

It they are correct then what do 'take and have' mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are grammatical, and meaningful.

*Take X* can mean "to eat or consume" if X can be considered in some way medicinal or resolving an abnormal condition (think of it being related to *intake* or *take in*).  If it is not medicinal, then it has its literal meaning.

> Take some aspirin (eat some aspirin to cure a headache)
>
> Take some candy (this means remove candy from where it is and place in your hand/possession, not necessarily to eat it)
>
> Take some water (can mean to drink water to "cure" thirst, or remove a quantity of water from somewhere and place in your possession/control somehow)

There's a lot of nouns, including ones that describe food or eating events, that can be used with *have* that essentially mean "receive/take/get X" where doing that is some sort of event or action that consumes a stretch of time.  *Have some food* versus *get some food* can imply that you will sit down and eat, instead of grabbing the food and going.

> Have dinner with us (Sit down and spend some time to eat with us)
>
> Have a good time at the party (Party will consume a stretch of time)

And of course, if you want someone to have something, but get it themselves, you can use *have X* imperatively.  This isn't really related to what X is.

> Have an aspirin for your headache (If I'm not handing you one, I'm asking you to go to the medicine cabinet and get it yourself).

Comment: Thanks, I got what you said abou 'take' but not about 'have '. A says I am hungry. B says me too, Let's have something to eat. What does 'have' mean here? He can simply say Le's eat something for example.

Comment: *Let's have something to eat* - that's an invitation to a sit down meal - or stop what you are doing at the current moment for a while at least - more than just eating something.

Answer (score 0):

In context 'take' means 'bring along' or 'get' the item to eat or drink.

In context 'Let's have something to eat/drink' is equivalent (the same as) to 'Let's eat/drink something'.

As their meanings are different, have and take are not equivalent.

Comment: I couldn't find 'have something to eat' in dictionaries.